# JMenu and JMenuItems have thin orange border that I cannot change

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, menu, uicolor

I have been using the `UIManager` to change the coloring scheme on my GUI. For example I use this for `JMenuItems`:

```
UIManager.put("MenuItem.foreground", new ColorUIResource(255, 255, 255));
UIManager.put("MenuItem.background", new ColorUIResource(51, 51, 51));
UIManager.put("MenuItem.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(232, 232, 232));
```

For some unknown reason, a 1 pixel orange border appears around my `JMenuItems` and `JMenus`. I don't understand why and I checked all the keys from http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-uimanager-color-keys-list. Does anybody know how to change the color that borders the `JMenuItems` and `JMenus`? If it can't be done with the `UIManager` that is fine for a solution too.

Comment: If you try a simple Swing JFrame with a menu and nothing else, do you still get it ? I am trying to get at is it on your machine or in the code ? Does it happen on a different machine (If possible different hardware) ?

Comment: In other words post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org) so we can see if the problem is the code, the LAF, the Java version or the OS.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 9.04, Java 1.6, default LAF.

A SSCCE would be tough, because I am building on top of other stuff and those UIManager lines above sum up all I've done. For some reason orange is a selection color before I did anything. If that isn't apart of the default LAF, then something hidden is causing the orange selection border. There should be a way to override or set this border color right?

Comment: Is it the default java metal LAF? If not:

Orange is the default selection color in Ubuntu, as far as I recall. It could be that the Gtk LAF does not parse those values correctly. Try with the Metal LAF.

Comment: The metal LAF takes care of that orange border, which is nice, but now their is a blue-ish border and other things have changed. Is there anyway I can customise just that one part of the LAF so the border isn't some random color decided by the LAF?

Answer (score 0):

well i dig into it for a while didn't find a fine answer so that what i did,
jmnenu.getpopupmenu().setborder(border); // choose a border you can choose the color for it or the size of it that the best i could come with in an easy solution
hope it helps if not for you for someone else

Comment: forgot to add (lol) important info' to eliminate the border create this border

jmenu.getPopupMenu().setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 0)); // jmenu is of type JMenu and not JMenuBar